# Why is my Nikon D3200 display not changing in manual mode?

Tags: nikon, display, nikon-d3200

I just got my Nikon d3200. When I use manual mode and change my aperture, shutter speed or ISO, nothing changes on the screen. I found the same working in Canon. Is there any setting that I should change?

Comment: What mode are you trying to take photos in? Live View? Fully automatic? Manual with Auto-ISO?

Comment: http://www.nikonusa.com/pdf/manuals/dslr/D3200_EN.pdf‎

Comment: @MichaelClark - I can't edit the question for him at the moment since there is a pending edit that I already reviewed, but it appears that he is talking about the exposure preview mode on Canon cameras where they emulate the expected exposure based on current exposure settings.  This is only applicable to Live View.

Answer (score 2):

The Nikon D3200 - as all Nikon DSLRs - do not offer an *Exposure-Priority* Live-View. The image stays the same no matter what you do and corresponds roughly to the *metered* exposure.

Canon offers Exposure-Priority and Display-Priority modes via an option in the custom menu.   Sony does mostly the same. Unfortunately most other brands do not show the simulated exposure either which makes Live-View much less useful than it could be.

Comment: i am using manual mode with auto iso. for example if i change my aperture in my frnds canon d screen also changes accordingly, i cant do the same in my nikon :(

Comment: As I said, that is correct. To be clear, you are using Live-View to compose instead of the viewfinder. Nikon just always shows you the same image while Canon (and Sony BTW) simulates the exposure. This is the distinction between *Exposure-Priority* and *Display-Priority*.